# Visualization while recording : Graph too zoomed in/out of view and starts from top

Tags: android, android-canvas, visualization, audio-recording

I am trying to do visualization while recording. I am able to draw visualization on canvas. But the drawing starts at top of the view and too much zoomed. how can show this at the centre. Below is my code

VisualizerView.java :

```
package com.example.hp.recordingvisualization;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VisualizerView extends View {
private static final int LINE_WIDTH = 1; // width of visualizer lines
private static final int LINE_SCALE = 75; // scales visualizer lines
private List<Float> amplitudes; // amplitudes for line lengths
private int width; // width of this View
private int height; // height of this View
private Paint linePaint; // specifies line drawing characteristics
private float[] mPoints;


// constructor
public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); // call superclass constructor
    linePaint = new Paint(); // create Paint for lines
    linePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN); // set color to green
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_WIDTH); // set stroke width
}

// called when the dimensions of the View change
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    width = w; // new width of this View
    height = h; // new height of this View
    amplitudes = new ArrayList<Float>(width / LINE_WIDTH);
}

// clear all amplitudes to prepare for a new visualization
public void clear() {
    amplitudes.clear();
}

// add the given amplitude to the amplitudes ArrayList
public void addAmplitude(float amplitude) {
    amplitudes.add(amplitude); // add newest to the amplitudes ArrayList

    // if the power lines completely fill the VisualizerView
    if (amplitudes.size() * LINE_WIDTH >= width) {
        amplitudes.remove(0); // remove oldest power value
    }
}

// draw the visualizer with scaled lines representing the amplitudes
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // for each item in the amplitudes ArrayList
    for (float power : amplitudes) {
        float scaledHeight = power / LINE_SCALE; // scale the power
        if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < amplitudes.size() * 4) {
            mPoints = new float[amplitudes.size() * 4];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < amplitudes.size() - 1; i++) {
            mPoints[i * 4] = width * i / (amplitudes.size() - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = scaledHeight / 2
                    + ((amplitudes.get(i) + 128)) * (scaledHeight / 2) / 128;
            mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = width * (i + 1) / (amplitudes.size() - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 3] =scaledHeight / 2
                    + ((amplitudes.get(i+1) + 128)) * (scaledHeight / 2)
                    / 128;
        }
        // draw a line representing this item in the amplitudes ArrayList
        canvas.drawLines(mPoints, linePaint);
    }
}
}
```

RecordingActivity.java :

```
package com.example.hp.recordingvisualization;

/**
 * Created by hp on 11/3/2015.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;



public class RecordingActivity extends Activity {
public static final String DIRECTORY_NAME_TEMP = "AudioTemp";
public static final int REPEAT_INTERVAL = 40;
private TextView txtRecord;

VisualizerView visualizerView;

private MediaRecorder recorder = null;

File audioDirTemp;
private boolean isRecording = false;


private Handler handler; // Handler for updating the visualizer
// private boolean recording; // are we currently recording?

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);

    visualizerView = (VisualizerView) findViewById(R.id.visualizer);

    txtRecord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRecord);
    txtRecord.setOnClickListener(recordClick);

    audioDirTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            DIRECTORY_NAME_TEMP);
    if (audioDirTemp.exists()) {
        deleteFilesInDir(audioDirTemp);
    } else {
        audioDirTemp.mkdirs();
    }

    // create the Handler for visualizer update
    handler = new Handler();
}

OnClickListener recordClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!isRecording) {
            // isRecording = true;

            txtRecord.setText("Stop Recording");

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audioDirTemp + "/audio_file"
                    + ".mp3");

            OnErrorListener errorListener = null;
            recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
            OnInfoListener infoListener = null;
            recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
                isRecording = true; // we are currently recording
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(updateVisualizer);

        } else {

            txtRecord.setText("Start Recording");

            releaseRecorder();
        }

    }
};

private void releaseRecorder() {
    if (recorder != null) {
        isRecording = false; // stop recording
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateVisualizer);
        visualizerView.clear();
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}

public static boolean deleteFilesInDir(File path) {

    if( path.exists() ) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {

            }
            else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    releaseRecorder();
}

Runnable updateVisualizer = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isRecording) // if we are already recording
        {
            // get the current amplitude
            int x = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            visualizerView.addAmplitude(x); // update the VisualizeView
            visualizerView.invalidate(); // refresh the VisualizerView

            // update in every second
            handler.postDelayed(this, REPEAT_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
};


}
```

activity_recording.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#231f20" >

<com.example.hp.recordingvisualization.VisualizerView
    android:id="@+id/visualizer"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRecord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Start Recording"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To center the drawing, you need to calculate the `width` and `height`. Do this in the `onDraw()` method.

   ```
   width = canvas.getWidth();
   height = canvas.getHeight();
   ```

   Then calculate the center of canvas (x,y) = (width/2, height/2). You need to draw all your points around this center point (x,y).
2. As far as scaling in concerned, you could choose `canvas.scale(scalefactor, x,y )`, instead of scaling all the amplitudes. This is simple and easy to maintain.